# SOAP UI : How to add testsuite property from Setup Script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to read a excel file from Setup Script in Test Suite and add the testSuite level the properties at run time.

I am not able to set the context to testSuite so that I can use addProperty() method.

```
def testSuite = testRunner.testCase.testSuite    testSuite.addProperty("rowCount",rowCount)
```

Can some one help me understand how the above can be done

Answer (score 2):

If you're using groovy from a `setup Script` in `TestSuite` level: `log`,`runner`,`context` and `testSuite` variables are available, so in your case to set property on `TestSuite` simply use:

`testSuite.setPropertyValue('rowCount', rowCount)`

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

You should just add a *properti-object*, to your testcase (right click in the testcase and add Properti). Then when you run, it will work.. (adding the rowCount)